# How should I override the default value in __init__ method in python?

Tags: python

```
class GoogleAuth(ApiAttributeMixin, object):
    def __init__(self, settings_file='settings.yaml',http_timeout=None):
```

here I want to change the default value of settings_file to my own path

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. For a different default value, change what it is set to in the definition of `__init__()`. You can override the default when calling the function by specifying the keyword argument name and a different value: i.e. `ga = GoogleAuth(settings_file='my_settings.yaml')`

Comment: @Annadurai could you provide code of ApiAttributeMixin? (only code of `__init__`)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a new path in the definition.

```
class GoogleAuth(ApiAttributeMixin, object):
    def __init__(self, settings_file='settings.yaml',http_timeout=None):
       settings_file = '/var/myfile.yaml'
```

Comment: class GoogleAuth(ApiAttributeMixin, object):
    def __init__(self, settings_file='settings.yaml',http_timeout=None):
        settings_file = '/var/myfile.yaml'
        super(GoogleAuth, self).__init__(settings_file = settings_file,http_timeout=None) 
GoogleAuth.__init__ = GoogleAuth

cat able to override it. @Mayur

Comment: `ga=GoogleAuth(settings_file='another.yaml')` will behave quite unexpectedly!

Comment: @Annadurai Can you please be more clear about the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

So, one of your classes is inherited from another one. And when we're talking about default value in `__init__` - that means the value, which will be used when no specific value was provided. For instance:

```py
google_auth = GoogleAuth()  # default value for `settings_file` will be used
google_auth = GoogleAuth(http_timeout=23)  # default value for `settings_file` will be used
google_auth = GoogleAuth(settings_file='specific_one.yaml')  # specified one will be used instead of default
...
```

And most likely your base class `ApiAttributeMixin` has its own default value for `settings_file` parameter. So you want to override that default value with another one for your subclass `GoogleAuth`.

Let's say you want `google_settings.yaml` as the default for `settings_file` parameter in your `GoogleAuth` class. The code will look like the following:

```py
class ApiAttributeMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, settings_file='settings.yaml', http_timeout=None):
        pass


class GoogleAuth(ApiAttributeMixin, object):

    def __init__(self, settings_file='google_settings.yaml', http_timeout=None):
        super(GoogleAuth, self).__init__(settings_file, http_timeout)
```